# External content in FTS4 SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

Здравствуйте! Я реализовываю полнотекстовый поиск в своём Android приложении. У меня есть две таблицы:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_1 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, column TEXT, text_column TEXT)");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_2 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, column TEXT, text_column TEXT)");
```

Также я создаю FTS таблицу и в content записываю название моих таблиц.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4 (content=('table_1', 'table_2'), text_column)");
```

Затем заполняю таблицы данными:

```
db.execSQL("INTO table_1 (column, text_column) VALUES ('5', 'table_1')");
db.execSQL("INTO table_2 (column, text_column) VALUES ('7', 'table_2')");
```

И обновляю FTS таблицу:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO fts_table (docid, text_column) SELECT _id, text_column FROM table_1");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO fts_table (docid, text_column) SELECT _id, text_column FROM table_2");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO fts_table(fts_table) VALUES('rebuild')");
```

Но когда я делаю запрос, ничего не происходит:

```
String[] selectionArgs = { "table*" };
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH ?", selectionArgs);
```

Как записать данные из нескольких таблиц в одну FTS таблицу?

P. S. Мне кажется, что ошибка в строке:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4 (content=('table_1', 'table_2'), text_column)");
```

Comment: А заполняете ли вы таблицы данными? `INTO table_1` вместо `INSERT INTO table_1` (аналогично для `table_2`) выглядит более чем подозрительно.

Comment: Да, заполняю. В вопросе опечатка.

Comment: В консольном sqlite3 на локальной машине получилось такой финт проделать? Что-то у меня не особо :) Ещё, насколько я помню, в android отключен FTS4, только FTS3. По крайней мере в версиях до 4.0

Comment: @Denis исправьте тогда опечатку, чтобы вам снова это не предложили в качестве причины.

Comment: Пишу для Android >= 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве *content* в FTS4 sqlte3 нельзя указывать несколько таблиц, только 0 или 1.

```
$ ./sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table_1 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, column TEXT, text_column TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4 (content='table_1', text_column);
sqlite> INSERT INTO table_1 (column, text_column) VALUES (5, 'table_1');
sqlite> INSERT INTO fts_table (docid, text_column) SELECT _id, text_column FROM table_1;
sqlite> INSERT INTO fts_table(fts_table) VALUES('rebuild');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH 'table*';
table_1
```